# access my array of structs in my template

Tags: go, go-templates

I'm passing an array of structs to my template, the data is there but I can't find a way to access specific data, I tried many things already, here it is

My Struct

```
type Data struct {
  Destination string
  IData interface{}
}
```

then in my controller I have

```
users := []models.User {}

userRow := models.User{Name: "jon", Email: "jon@mail.com"}
users = append(users, userRow)
users2 := users

data := models.Data{
    Destination: "content",
    IData: users,
}

data2 := models.Data{
    Destination: "content",
    IData: users2,
}

dataFinal := []models.Data{}
dataFinal = append(dataFinal, data)
dataFinal = append(dataFinal, data2)
```

and this is my template, though this didn't seem to work, it does show the raw data but can't seem to access the name specifically.

```
{{define "content"}}
<h2>THIS IS THE BODY CONTENT</h2>

<ul>
    {{.}}
    {{range .}}
    <li>{{.}}</li>
    {{end}}
</ul>
{{end}}
```

edit:
project: https://github.com/og2/go-og2-mvc

you may wanna run:

**go get github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql**

**go get github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter**

for it to work and should be just fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pipeline value that you pass to the `"content"` template execution is `dataFinal`, then you have to use two `{{range}}` actions as `dataFinal` itself is a slice (of type `[]models.Data`), and `Data.IData` is also a slice (of type `[]model.User`).

Inside the inner `{{range}}` you may refer to the `User.Name` like `.Name`:

```
<li>{{.Name}}</li>
```

See this working example:

```
const templ = `{{define "content"}}
<h2>THIS IS THE BODY CONTENT</h2>

<ul>
    {{.}}
    {{range .}}
    <ul>
       {{range .IData}}
       <li>{{.Name}}</li>
       {{end}}
    </ul>
    {{end}}
</ul>
{{end}}`

// Parsing and executing the template:
t := template.Must(template.New("").Parse(templ))
fmt.Println(t.ExecuteTemplate(os.Stdout, "content", dataFinal))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/-xrWWCfFDQ)):

```
<h2>THIS IS THE BODY CONTENT</h2>

<ul>
    [{content [{jon jon@mail.com}]} {content [{jon jon@mail.com}]}]

    <ul>

       <li>jon</li>

    </ul>

    <ul>

       <li>jon</li>

    </ul>

</ul>
<nil>
```

Comment: Nice. Didn't know template engine is smart enough to assert or reflect IData provided is slice underneath, not just interface{}

Comment: @Uvelichitel The template engine uses reflection. `Execute()` and `ExecuteTemplate()` take the data as `interface{}`, so if this wouldn't be the case, you couldn't even range over a single passed slice (which is wrapped in an `interface{}` value).

Comment: @icza it seems to work fine but as I added more array of structs passed kinda got messed up, since in ExecuteTemplate you can only pass one data right, so what I'm doing is passing an array of structs, so you have there different structs or objects if you want to call it that, would I need 3 ranges? it's hard to explain but lemme update above and also add my project so you can have a broader look.

Comment: nvm I just figured it out, thank you very much. marked it as answered. Just as a side note, the problem was that I was getting the rows from the SQL in the wrong order.